# Creating a function type where the return type depends on the existence of an optional parameter

Tags: typescript

Consider the following JS function and example usage:

```js
const fooInteractor = function(state, foo) {
  if (foo) {
    return {...state, foo}
  } else {
    return state.foo
  }
}

const state = {foo: 'foo', other: 'data'};
fooInteractor(state); // returns 'foo'
fooInteractor(state, 'bar'); // return {foo: 'bar', other: 'data'}

// we pass this function around generically and use it to interact with state
function interacts(state, interactorFn) {
  // ie interactorFn(state);
}

interacts(state, fooInteractor);
```

How can I type this in TS land?

I can define a type and interaction with that type that Typescript is happy with:

```js
type StateInteractor {
  (state: State): string
  (state: State, value: string): State
}
function interact(state: State, stateFn: StateInteractor) {
  const data: string = stateFn(state);
  const changedState: State = stateFn(state, data);
  // etc
}
```

However, when it actually comes to implementing `StateInteractor` I'm having issues:

```js
const fooInteractor: StateInteractor = function(state: State, foo?: string) {
  if (foo) {
    return {...state, foo} as State
  } else {
    return state.foo as string
  }
}
/*
Type '(state: State, foo?: string) => string | State' is not assignable to type 'StateInteractor'.
  Type 'string | State' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
*/
```

I also can't get arrow functions / lambda to work.

Note that I **can** do this with function overloading:

```js
function fooInteractor(state: State): string
function fooInteractor(state: State, value: string): State
function fooInteractor(state: State, value?: string) {
  if (value) {
    return {...state, foo: value} as State
  } else {
    return state.foo as string
  }
}

// This compiles and works as expected
const typedFooInteractor: StateInteractor = fooInteractor
interact(someState, typedFooInteractor)
```

But this is super ugly and weird, and requires that I redefine the StateInteractor type (via overloading) every single time I implement one.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbG3bW) do what you want it to?

Comment: @fedonev looks like it! I went down this road before but got as far as `<V extends string | undefined>`, which doesn't work. I was not aware of `<V extends string | undefined = undefined>` as an option and have no idea what it even means!... If you want to post it as an answer that would be helpful

Comment: I know the feeling.  My approach is to yell at the compiler and randomly type `T`s and `K`s until the red squiggly lines disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can squeeze the overload logic into a generic function signature using [Generic Parameter Defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) and a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) as the return value.  [Playground version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCUIGMD2AnAJgDwDOwuAlgHYDmANFPJSAHwCwAUBwPRdT4QAzKtHhQBAV0qZg5bJSihIUAO4ALbMWi4IwcbnkA3eABtx0fpEr5iUOQ3nxc1cQFsIlYB0XQ4iCAEkPCFx4aTwoVEIYKAgADyQrG18kegA1GPj3ayhSChooAB8oSX4hSgh8COKrQWF8ZgAKUj8ALlh6I1MIAH421IBKCOYodLiE7Nyqaihu2AQkKDbJ-I4OCSkZOyokEOkm+Yg25Ih6ZqQAMUojg8Cd0OA8QYBvDigoHEpSPkR4JbIpqpnCCXfZ+foAble7zkX0wqkY1Aqx2ufkBBxBQPo+B+EKhPBiwEwHAAvqt2B8vgJsNhbsF7ngUUhabsHrgqqCkIyTmJqb0cv8aINkMMXuw3uQBFAGlTsM8oW9tLp9FAngA6dWYnnYUliqDEmLGTQq+VQRV6eRA1UyqE6nVk-FIL7kTycckw4D81GoJ4ytoAchlfvo2GAqmC-uxCD9xMhbs+HuI6nExnwACFgdSqjLmfTcByIBCoPizfobAHqX6OBTsMYIKrjNhqE0kyn0+dqf0q+6ci20xBjlnqTmwnnNX6AEaOP2F4s6c0q31QCdT4Oh8NLyPwaNdz41usNpuJ7DJvvHfpAA)

`V extends string | undefined = undefined` (the generic default) says `V` is either string or undefined and by default undefined.  The conditional return `V extends string ? State : string` uses ternary syntax to return based on `V`'s type.

```js
type State = Record<string, any>

// define a function type whose return value depends on an argument
type StateInteractor = <S extends State, V extends string | undefined = undefined>(state: S, value?: V) => V extends string ? State : string 

// define an instance
const fooInteractor: StateInteractor = (state: State, foo?: string) => {
  if (foo) {
    return {...state, foo}
  } else {
    return state.foo
  }
}

// test it
const state = {foo: 'foo', other: 'data'};
const shouldBeFoo = fooInteractor(state); // returns 'foo'
const shouldBeState = fooInteractor(state, 'bar'); // return {foo: 'bar', other: 'data'}
```

Comment: OK so taking this example and reimplementing it in my actual code I came across a really bizzare thing: take your example above and try to cast `return state.foo` to string (which it should be), e.g. `return state.foo as string`. Now the code fails. This actually only works for implementations if the return type that maps to the optional parameter gets cast as `any`. This is deeply bizarre and consumers of the API don't have to worry about it, only function implementers.

Comment: OK I'm now less and less convinced that the implementation typing works at all. You can swap the return values around so your return types don't map to what the type asks. The interface (how callers interact with the function type) works so it's good enough for my needs (appeasing the compiler)

Comment: I wasn't focusing on the entire abstraction, just on the generic replacement for the overload.  I dumped in a vanilla state def `type State = Record<string, any>`.  That's why foo is `any` in the toy implementation.